# Filling Thousands of Closed Loops at once

Tags: mesh

I have a huge set of building plan outlines exported from QGis (as curves) they are all closed polygons (imports as a curve) and are set to the right height, but I need to fill and extrude them all (thousands). I tried converting it to a mesh and selecting one linked loop at a time and filling, extruding but it’ll take me forever… is there a better way to fill thousands of connected loops/curves at once?

Comment: Yes: *Geometry Nodes*. ...would that be an option for you? Or you use the modifier *Solidify*.

Comment: If you have just building as outlines - Convert to Mesh, Extrude and Fill (F) ... in these three clicks for all of them. If you want to stay with Curve check Curve's Properties if Shape is set as 2D (not 3D) with Fill mode > Front. If curves are not position at the same level, you would have to separate them and Set Origin to Geometry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it well you can go in edit mode, make sure to be in edge selection mode

[image]
[image]

Open the search bar with <kbd>F3</kbd> and type non manifold

[image]

Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill

[image]

Warning: in my exemple the outer edge was selected as well so I it created a huge face and I have to delete it (you can see some Z-fighting in the picture bellow as I didn't deleted it yet)

[image]